# At what point is a LINQ data source determined?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, extension-methods

Given the below two samples of LINQ, at what point is a LINQ data source determined?

```
int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
IEnumerable<int> linqToOjects = numbers.Where(x => true);

XElement root = XElement.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> linqToXML = root.Elements("Address").Where(x => true);
```

My understanding is that the underlying code used to query these two different data sources lives within the IEnumerable object produced by the LINQ methods.

My question is, at what point exactly is it determined whether code will be generated to use the Linq To Objects library or the Linq To XML library?

I would assume that the underlying code (the code which actually does the work of querying the data) used to query these data sources exist within their own libraries and are called upon dependent on the data source. I have looked at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ to look at the code of the Where clause/extension method thinking that the call to the desired provider might be in there, but it appears to be generic.

How is the magic which goes into the IEnumerable determined?

Comment: `IEnumerable` are not determined until it change to a "determined" type such as when you call a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` on it. But the `IEnumerable` itself is never determined.

Comment: Thanks - I should have worded it as the IEnumerable instance.

Comment: The only time this kinda matters is when you are working with IQueryable.  Otherwise isn't all pretty much linq to objects.   (But the actual implmentation that is used is choosen at compile time based on what classes you provide as input and what extension methods are resolved.)

Answer (score 6):

The "data source" is determined immediately. For example, in your first example, the return value of `Where` is an object that implements `IEnumerable<int>` (the `Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<int>` class in particular) that has a dependency on the `numbers` object (stored as a field). And the return value of `Where` in the second example is an enumerable object that has an dependency on the xml element object. So even before you start enumerating, the resulting enumerable knows where to get the data from.

Comment: When you say _the resulting enumerable knows where to get the data from_, does it also know **how** to get the data at that point, as in the code within the enumerable used to actually query the data (stored as a field) because I imagine the facilities used to query an array and xml object is very different.

Comment: @Brummy It doesn't *need* to know how.  It is the responsibility of that data source to expose its data using the `IEnumerable` interface, so all the `Where` method needs to do is use that interface and allow the underlying data source to do whatever it needs to do to get the data.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, at what point exactly is it determined whether code
>   will be generated to use the Linq To Objects library or the Linq To
>   XML library?

I think there is no code generation. LINQ just uses the datasource  [enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

You have a class that implement [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a
>   collection of a specified type.

So you can use the method [GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.

And this all LINQ needs to work, an [enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your example you use the Where LINQ extension method to apply some filter.

```
IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

In the implementation we need to:
- get the enumerator (source.GetEnumerator())
- iterate through the collection and apply the filter (predicate)

In the [Enumerable reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) you have the implementation of the method Where. You can see that he uses some specific implementation for array (TSource[]) and list (List), but he uses [WhereEnumerableIterator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,44b8532e11187695) for all the other classes that implement IEnumerable. 
So there is no code generation, the code is there.

I think you can understand the implementation of the class [WhereEnumerableIterator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,44b8532e11187695), you only need to understand first how to implement  [IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,32d865ea5398382a,references) you can see the implementation of MoveNext. They call **source.GetEnumerator()** and then they iterate through the collection (**enumerator.MoveNext()**) and apply the filter (**predicate(item)**).

```
public override bool MoveNext() {
    switch (state) {
        case 1:
            enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            state = 2;
            goto case 2;
        case 2:
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                TSource item = enumerator.Current;
                if (predicate(item)) {
                    current = item;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Dispose();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[XContainer.GetElement](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,14a63861e383a94e,references) returns an IEnumerable using the [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword.

> When you use the yield keyword in a statement, you indicate that the
>   method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an iterator.
>   Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an explicit
>   extra class (the class that holds the state for an enumeration, see
>   IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the IEnumerable and
>   IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.

Thanks to the magic of yield keyword we can obtain an IEnumerable, and we can enumerate the collection. And this is the only thing LINQ needs.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I was just looking at that source code! Am I right in thinking that the object returned from the `GetElement` method (`XContainer`) should have a GetEnumerator method? Looking through the Microsoft reference code I can't see it.

Comment: I see your point now. The object returned by the XContainer.GetElement method is an IEnumerable<XElement>, so, we can do:  
root.Elements("Address").GetEnumerator(). And LINQ uses this enumerator. But, how the GetElement method returns an IEnumerable? Using the yield keyword. I modified my answer to show you.